# Fetch markers on map with firebase and react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-maps

Hi, I'm trying to fetch datas from my database to my react native app on a map with Firebase.

But I don't found the way to fetch only datas which have the latitude and the longitude for beeing shown on the screen.

I try many things but I can't listen to the latitude AND the longitude with Firebase query.

So please how should i do the query? Sorry for the bad English I'm 12 and i'm french.
Thanks

---

Comment: You should watch geofire, works pretty well

Comment: You need to provide a minimal example of code to get help here with some specific question related to what you tried.